# O(n/2) - можно ли не учитывать знаменатель?

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

Слышал такое мнение, что коэффициент при `n` при описании сложности алгоритма можно не учитывать. Правда ли это?

Я считаю, что это мнение ошибочно, поскольку (особенно на больших входных данных) разница между `O(n/2)` и `O(n)` будет довольно существенна.

Comment: Нет, не можно. Нужно!! Разницы — с точки зрения сложности — никакой.

Comment: Уважаемый ТС, вам полезно будет изучить что такое О-большое с точки зрения определений и теории пределов. Хорошее понимание основ и свойств О-большого позволит не задавать такие вопросы. **О-большое не про скорость работы**, а про то как меняется эта скорость с размером данных. И для O(n/2) и для O(n) увеличение размера данных в два раза приведёт к увеличению времени исполнения в два раза. Ни о чём другом О-большое не говорит.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, это правда. Константные множители игнорируются при **описании сложности** алгоритмов, будь они даже миллион или наоборот, очень маленькие. При **достаточно большом** размере данных алгоритм с лучшей сложностью обгонит алгоритм с худшей сложностью с намного меньшей константой.

Конечно, они оказывают влияние на **практическую производительность**, и некоторые теоретически самые быстрые алгоритмы на практике уступают алгоритмам с худшей сложностью, поскольку размеры данных, на которых они выиграют, не используются или просто нереальны.